# how to change the value of a certain variable everyday at 00:00

Tags: android, service, repeatingalarm

So I am working on a logger(xposed module, not mine, I just copied the source and now modifying it for my preference) 
I am not good at app development so I can't work this out myself. 
What I am looking for exactly is a way that the name of the output file be changed everyday at 00:00(because that's a new day's start, I am trying to keep everyday's log in a sprays fine) 
So can anyone please provide a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

To schedule an operation to be performed at a certain time of day, you'll want to look into using the `AlarmManager` class, which allows you to do exactly this. You can find the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

To rename a file that already exists, you'll want to look into using the `File` class, specifically the `renameTo()` method. You can read more about this in the docs here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Hope this helps you get started!

Comment: Thanks for providing the direction in which I should look, I would like to get a little elaboration on how I should use AlarmManager

Comment: Read this Google guide. It will show you the beginning steps of setting up a task to fire at a certain time of day: [http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) It shows you example code for each step.